# Cloning a Windows 11 MacBook Pro Boot Camp partition

Tags: bootcamp, partition, carbon-copy-cloner

I recently got a new Lenovo dedicated gaming laptop and am wondering how to go about cloning, if possible, a Boot Camp Windows 11 partition. I have many files and games from my childhood I cannot find online anymore and installing it on the new PC which comes with two 1 TB SSDs?

Comment: While it **is** a Boot Camp partition, I believe this is more of a Windows question.

Comment: What is the model year of the MacBook Pro and what version of macOS is installed?

Comment: Are you asking about using the MBP bootcamp partition on the Lenovo? Or just getting files from it.  The former seems like it might be problematic (due to lack of right drivers / and other configuration in Windows for the Lenovo)